Binary Search: Nearest K Elements
I tried to solve the "find nearest K elements in a sorted array" problem of Leetcode using binary search approach but unable to figure out why its not working.
LeetCode Problem Link:
text
Problem Description:
Given a sorted integer array arr, two integers k and x, return the k closest integers to x in the array. The result should also be sorted in ascending order.
An integer a is closer to x than an integer b if:

|a - x| < |b - x|, or

|a - x| == |b - x| and a < b


Example 1:
Input: arr = [1,2,3,4,5], k = 4, x = 3
Output: [1,2,3,4]
Tried writing the program to solve K nearest numbers in a sorted array:
The program make sure that it never overwrite the best solution found so far by introducing minimumDiff variable:
    public List<Integer> findClosestElements(int[] arr, int k, int x) {
        int startIndex = 0;
        int low = 0;
        int high = arr.length - k;
        int mid = -1;
        int minimumDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int diff = 0;
        while(low <= high) {
            mid = low + (high - low)/2;
            if((mid + k  arr.length) || (x - arr[mid] > arr[mid + k] - x)) {
                low = mid + 1;
                diff = x - arr[mid];
            }else {
                high = mid - 1;
                diff = arr[mid + k] - x;
            }
            if(minimumDiff > diff) {
                minimumDiff = diff;
                startIndex = mid;
            }
        }
        List<Integer> nearestKElements = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=startIndex; i<startIndex+k; i++){
            nearestKElements.add(arr[i]);
        }
        return nearestKElements;
}

However it still fails for input:
Input: [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], k = 3 and x = 3
Output: [4,4,4]
Expected Output: [2, 3, 4]
Questions:
1.Can you please help me know how should the program behave in case "x - arr[mid] == arr[mid + k] - x". Currently my program always move towards left but thats failing for some test cases as mentioned above?

Please limit yourself to one question per question. Make sure the (preferably one) piece of code you are sharing is a [mre] and is relevant to your question. Other tips: [ask]

Well I shared multiple piece of code because you wanted me to share everything that I tried. Asked questions are logically related to this program only, I dont see a need of creating multiple questions for them specially when members are all time ready to label a question as duplicate. I see some members are still tagging as possible duplicate even though questions are completely different.

Time to take the [tour]? How Stack Overflow works is you ask a question, someone answers it, you accept the answer, they get imaginary internet points. If it is not clear what an acceptable answer has to satisfy and/or it has to answer multiple questions after reviewing multiple pieces of code, fewer people are going to engage with the question. If you are interested in improving your chances: one clear question, [mre] showing the problem in action.

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site where the question has one definite canonical answer.  You've already posted the correct code in your question.  You're asking people to explain why your code is incorrect, which probably fits better with Reddit's r/javahelp.

sure, i have noted down the comments and will try to improve it for future questions.

@teapot418 I have simplified the question. Hope that would help community members to help me out.

@GilbertLeBlanc Can you please help if possible

Sure.  Write a LeetcodeDriver Java class so you can test your code in your own IDE with a debugger.

I have debugged it and also mentioned the problem with my solution. I am looking for help to solve it.

Why the expected output in the failed example should be [4,4,4]? I would expext [4,5,5]

exactly: 5 is closer to 5 than 4, because |5 - 5| is 0 while |4 - 5| is 1

@gimix my bad, I have updated the inputs. x = 3 instead of 5

@gimix Corrrect Inputs: Input: [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5], k = 3 and x = 3
Output: [4,4,4]
Expected Output: [2, 3, 4]

Posting the answer that I was able to figure out:
public List<Integer> findClosestElements(int[] arr, int k, int x) {

    int left = 0, right = arr.length - k;
    int start = 0;
    while (left <= right) {
        int midpoint = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (((midpoint + k) < arr.length ) && (x - arr[midpoint] > arr[midpoint + k] - x))    {
            left = midpoint + 1;
            start = left;
        }
        else {
            start = midpoint;
            right = midpoint - 1;
        }
    }
    start = (start == arr.length)?start - 1: start;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(k);
    for (int i = start; i < start + k; i++) {
        result.add(arr[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
}

